# When should one use jest snapshot testing vs just regular assertions in unit test?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

This question is just about unit tests.

Recently I've been reading a lot about snapshots and I'm really confused as to when exactly should I use snapshot testing vs just explicit assertions. I use react & jest & enzyme for unit testing

As far as I understand it definitely makes sense to use snapshot testing:
to check if the component rendered the way we expected it to with the expected props. That way we don't really have to have an assertion for each prop or each component that was rendered etc

Questions: 
1) But when it comes to user interactions like blur or click, there could be many cases. In that case does it make sense to have a snap for each of those testcases ? Say I have 10 different cases that I want to test for onBlur. Then does it make sense to have 10 different snaps for that? I know we can use serializers to filter out what we want to see on the snap but isn't just regular data driven test ( which contains input & expected output provided by developer ) with a single assertion just better?

2) How about when I have a component which in turn renders a couple of child components & those child components render their children etc. In that case I mount & then take the snapshot. That snap becomes really huge, Again I know we can tweak it by use of serializers. But really whats so great about snapshots in this case?

3) Isn't having too many snapshots in general a bad thing ?

I also came across some fancy tools like jest-glamor-react etc which can be used to get the most out of snapshot testing. But really how do I figure out which scenario is best tested using snapshots & which is best using regular assertions? I read a bunch of articles but some people are really impressed with snapshots but the examples are really basic. Some people are totally against it & think plain old assertions are way better. Can someone please share their views ?

Comment: A couple of opinions: https://kentcdodds.com/blog/effective-snapshot-testing

Answer (score 0):

> **Why snapshot testing?**

**No flakiness:** Because tests are run in a command line runner instead of a real browser or on a real phone, the test runner doesn't have to wait for builds, spawn browsers, load a page and drive the UI to get a component into the expected state which tends to be flaky and the test results become noisy.

**Fast iteration speed:** Engineers want to get results in less than a second rather than waiting for minutes or even hours. If tests don't run quickly like in most end-to-end frameworks, engineers don't run them at all or don't bother writing them in the first place.

**Debugging:** It's easy to step into the code of an integration test in JS instead of trying to recreate the screenshot test scenario and debugging what happened in the visual diff.

This was gotten from [here](https://facebook.github.io/jest/blog/2016/07/27/jest-14.html)

Now to answer your question:

I would use snapshot testing when I have to keep track of UI elements, ensuring nothing is changed without having intentionally made that change. Snapshot helps you achieve this.